# ActiveMQ - broker network setup

Tags: configuration, installation, activemq-classic, messagebroker, broker

I want to configure 3 activemq brokers (same machine or vm) that works together as broker network. What are the steps I need to follow ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use this guide? http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html

Please precise your question if you have difficulties with something about this manual.

Comment: I had some difficulties with manual. It clearly doesn't show how to configure multiple brokers. This might be hard since I'm newbie to this area. But I succeed after following this http://fusesource.com/docs/broker/5.4/clustering/index.html . Btw I configured 1 embedded broker and 3 remote brokers. I added all the brokers as static using this configuration <networkConnector uri="static:(tcp://host1:62001, tcp://host2:62001)" networkTTL="3"
duplex="true"/>. Only embedded broker web ui shows other brokers; but in the other brokers network setting it doesn't show. any idea about that ? Thanks.